# Determine when function is integrable in the region.

Tags: calculus, integration

Please help me to solve the following problem:

I am given $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{(x^2+y^3-2)^p}$ in a region $1 \leq x \leq 2, 1 \leq y \leq 3$. I have to find $p$ such that $f$ is integrable in this region (the integral over the region is finite).

Thanks a lot for hints and answers!

**Update:**

zhw hinted to translate the region of integration appropriately. I did that and got  $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{(x^2+2x+ y^3+3y^2+3y)^p}$ in a region $0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 2$. Unfortunately, I do not see how to apply polar coordinates here. Can you please advice?

Comment: Do you mean "integrable"?

Comment: I mean the integral over the region is finite, sorry, I will update my question now.

Comment: The only discontinuity within the region is at the corner $(1,1)$.  So I think it suffices to find the values of $p$ for which $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)} \frac{(x-1)(y-1)}{(x^2 + y^3-2)^p} < \infty$$

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I think that is too restrictive.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Never mind, what you wrote is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(1,1)$ is a blowup point. Fortunately

$$x^2 +y^3 - 2 = x^2-1 +y^3-1 = (x-1)(x+1) + (y-1)(y^2 + y + 1),$$

which is on the order of the distance of $(x,y)$ to $(1,1).$ If you translate the region of integration appropriately and go to polar coordinates, you'll find the crux of the matter is whether $\int_0^1\dfrac{r}{r^p}\, dr< \infty.$

Comment: Good answer.  This seems to lead to the same values of $p$ as my hint, though.  So why do you think my reduction is too restrictive?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang You're absolutely right, I didn't see your formulation correctly.

Comment: @zhw. I've changed the region of integration, but I do not see how to use polar coordinates - please check my answer update. Can you please suggest the substitution I need to use?

Comment: @Hedgehog  The new region of integration ia $[0,1]\times [0,2].$ The new function is

$$\frac{1}{[x(x+2) + y((y+1)^2 +y + 2)]^p}.$$

In this region the above function lies between constant multiples of $\dfrac{1}{(x + y)^p}.$

Comment: @user3472 Sorry, I don't have time.