# Computation of an integral over hemisphere.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Please help me to compute the integral over "top" surface of a hemisphere $$x^2+y^2+(z+1)^2 = R^2, y>0$$ $$\iint dz \ dx + y^2z \ dz\ dy.$$

I am not sure how to convert surface integral to double integral and which coordinates to choose.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Convert the surface integral to a double integral by considering the surface as the graph of a function on a disk.  Then use polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try. Can you please check my other question about integrable function and provide another hint?

Comment: [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2513508/2785)? Interesting question.  Perhaps more interesting than I have time for.  But I will look.

Comment: Yes, this one. Thanks in advance.